# Procedure to compile a new tex format

Tags: format-files

I created a new format based on plain (I used another hyphen file)
I compiled it using : tex --ini Myplain \dump
It compiled OK and created Myplain.fmt
How do I do to compile my .tex files using this new format?
Do I have to turn Myplain into a .exe file?
(I use TexLive 2018 and WinEdt)
Is there somewhere a written procedure to create, compile and use new formats?

Comment: If there is a small tex.exe in your texlive bin folder you can simply make a copy that you call myplain.exe. The alternative is to call tex --fmt=myplain.

Comment: at its simplest you don't need a new executable just `tex &Myplain myfile`  will process `myfile.tex`

Comment: Thanks, still encounter problems with files not found, etc., but will get there I think

Answer (score 1):

at its simplest you don't need a new executable just

```
tex &Myplain myfile
```

will process `myfile.tex`  (you may need `\&` depending on your commandline shell)
or avoiding `&` issues web2c implementations allow

```
tex -fmt Myplain myfile
```